# What should I share with my developer?

Tags: wallets, addresses

I have a stock exchange project that I hired to a developer. I'm okay with bitcoin but I am new to Ethereum. The developer is in the process of develop the Ether wallet. Like a regular stock market, I want an API generates unique ethereum addresses (connected to my cold wallet) for each registered members.  Which informations should I share with my developer to do it? can someone help me to redirect me as I am a newbie? I just want to in safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer should use use one of the many testnets available (Ropsten for example) to create dummy accounts to test the code before even going to mainnet (where I assume you have your account). So in this very early stage you don't need to share any of your account addresses, until the solidity / web3js code is built and well tested. Hope this helps.

Comment: He said that he is testing it as you said and tomorrow he will finish the project. So I just want to be prepared. what should he request from me? (e.g. JSON file, public address, private key or something else) For example, for bitcoin he requested Blockchain API Key and xpub key for receive payments into my wallet. Forgive me but im noob:( i dont want to give him private things accidently... Maybe he is a malicious person, i dont know. Thanks for care me!

Comment: As a general rule DO NOT share your private key. If you provide him with your mainnet account address then that should be sufficient for him to transfer you funds, provide authority to access / withdrawal from the contract etc..